# In node, why does require() fail to find a module I just installed with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

In a case that looks similar to [this problem,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594032/npm-module-installed-but-not-available) I have installed a module with npm, but `require('module')` can't find it.

```
my-machine:projectname me$ npm install express-csrf
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info version 0.2.1
npm info install express-csrf@0.3.3
npm info activate express-csrf@0.3.3
npm info build Success: express-csrf@0.3.3
npm ok
```

So far, so good. But then...

```
my-machine:projectname me$ node
> require('express-csrf')
Error: Cannot find module 'express-csrf'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
at require (module.js:346:19)
at [object Context]:1:1
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
```

npm says the package is there:

```
my-machine:projectname me$ npm ls express-csrf
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info version 0.2.1
express-csrf@0.3.3             active installed
npm ok
```

Note that the new module doesn't appear in the /usr/local/lib/node directory, but it does appear under /usr/local/lib/node/.npm

```
my-machine:projectname me$ ls /usr/local/lib/node/express-csrf*
ls: /usr/local/lib/node/express-csrf*: No such file or directory
my-machine:projectname me$ ls /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express-csrf*
0.3.3   active
```

Update: I should mention that everything works when I fully qualify the path in the `require` statements like so:

```
require('/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express-csrf/active/package/index.js')
```

Comment: Where are other modules that you can require? Maybe the path is slightly different because of some environment mismatch?

Comment: npm is at version 1.0.103, yours is a bit out of date...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade npm.

Your problem is that require() doesn't search the .npm folder.

You can solve this by upgrading npm so that it places files in the right spots. Alternatively, you can install your modules manually in a folder in the root of your project and require('../mymodule')

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I'll upgrade, and if that doesn't work, I'll try manually installing that one problematic module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows use:

```
export NODE_PATH="C:\Users\IMarek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules"
```

Comment: Could you post the revelant part of your blog post in the answer? Instead of posting a link on few answers.